# Unable to send post request using Android Studio/Dart?

Tags: android, android-studio, post, dart, flutter

I am trying to send a POST request to a remote server using flutter 1.0, dart 2.1 and Android Studio 3.2.1, but for some reason the remote server it is not receiving anything. I tried to use on my own server and I tried to use firebase as well, but without any luck. Can someone help me fix my error? Here is my code:

```
void addProduct(String title, String description, double price,
  String image) {
final Map<String, dynamic> productData = {
  'title': title,
  'description': description,
  'image': 'url',
  'price': price
};
http.post('https://fir-numbers.firebaseio.com/products.json', body: json.encode(productData));
final Product newProduct = Product(
    title: title,
    description: description,
    price: price,
    image: image,
    userEmail: _authenticatedUser.email,
    userId: _authenticatedUser.id);
_products.add(newProduct);
notifyListeners();
}
```

Also at the top i have

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

and in my pubspec.yaml i have

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  scoped_model: ^0.3.0
  http: ^0.12.0
```

Comment: You have to use Future, async and await for more info https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: isn't it that only when u want to fetch data from the server and if you u want to just send data you can do it without Future, async and await?

Comment: I'd call the code to a unit test and run it from there. This way the code runs on your computer, not in the emulator/device. This way you can check your code without influence of possible network configuration issues with your emulator/device.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, that sounds great, but im not very good with dart yet so i dont know how to write unit test codes yet

Comment: You don't need to write an unit test. It's just that IntelliJ/AndroidStudio/VSCode run Dart files in `test/xxx_test.dart` files directly with Dart and not on a device/emulator. You start with a normal `main() {...}`. That's all. You can't use stuff that depends on native like plugins, assets, and probably others.